# Unable to load CMS. Request timeout error

Tags: sitecore-client, mongodb

My local instance suddenly stopped working today. The CMS or the live site just doesn't load. When I tried to open it using SIM, it has this log.

No changes done to web.config or connection strings. I have checked logging into SQL Server and it works fine.

I even removed all project DLLs & patch configs from webroot.

Using sc8.2u3

> There is an issue with requesting
>   'http://mysite/sitecore/service/keepalive.aspx?ts=636523285992235501&reason=long'.
>   No error response provided.
>   System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted:
>   The operation has timed out.
>   Status: Timeout
>   ---> System.Net.WebException: The request
>   was aborted: The operation has timed out.    at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()    at
>   SIM.Base.WebRequestHelper.RequestAndGetResponse(Uri uri, Nullable`1
>   timeout, Nullable`1 readWriteTimeout, String cookies)    at
>   SIM.Base.WebRequestHelper.DownloadString(String url, Nullable`1
>   timeout, Nullable`1 readWriteTimeout)    at
>   SIM.Instances.InstanceHelper.StartInstance(Instance instance,
>   Nullable`1 timeout, String reason)    --- End of inner exception stack
>   trace ---    at SIM.Instances.InstanceHelper.StartInstance(Instance
>   instance, Nullable`1 timeout, String reason)    at
>   SIM.Tool.Base.InstanceHelperEx.PreheatInstance(Instance instance,
>   Exception& exception)

Error in Sitecore log file (but these errors were being logged even much before today's issue):

> ERROR Exception when executing agent
>   aggregation/automationCleanupService Exception:
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoQueryException Message: QueryFailure flag was not
>   master and slaveOk=false (response was { "$err" : "not master and
>   slaveOk=false", "code" : 13435 }). Source: MongoDB.Driver    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Internal.MongoReplyMessage`1.ReadHeaderFrom(BsonBuffer
>   buffer)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Internal.MongoConnection.ReceiveMessage[TDocument](BsonBinaryReaderSettings
>   readerSettings, IBsonSerializer serializer, IBsonSerializationOptions
>   serializationOptions)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Operations.QueryOperation`1.GetFirstBatch(IConnectionProvider
>   connectionProvider)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Operations.QueryOperation`1.Execute(IConnectionProvider
>   connectionProvider)    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>   at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.RangeScheduler.MongoDbRangeMap2.RemoveFinishedRanges()
>   at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Automation.Data.MongoDbAutomationProvider.GetOldestUnaggregatedRangeTimestamp()
>   at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Automation.Data.MongoDbAutomationProvider.RemoveAutomationTransitions(DateTime
>   oldestInclusive, DateTime latestExclusive)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Automation.Aggregation.Data.Processing.CleanupAgent.Execute()
>   at Sitecore.Analytics.Core.BackgroundService.Run()

Comment: Anything in Sitecore logs? Is Mongo running?

Comment: @MarekMusielak Mongo is running

Comment: Have you compared against a clean install? It sounds like you have deployed something that is running continuously in a loop.

Comment: @JayS. ah no....but even if so, shouldnt the CMS load.

Comment: Can you load ShowConfig.aspx? If even that won't load, that indicates some sort of failed deploy of config files.

Comment: Any recent changes at Mongo end ? Did you get chance to look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28263904/mongodb-c-queryfailure-flag-was-not-master-and-slaveok-false

Comment: Can you run this command from your we server "telnet [IP of the mongo server] 27017" and get a response from the server.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing same issue. Not sure what was the root cause problem. But changing Identity of App pool in IIS work for me.

Goto IIS -> Application Pools -> Select your website application Pool -> Click on Adavanced Settings -> Click on Identity -> Select any other identity like "ApplicationPoolIdentity" or "Network Service" or "Local System".

Note:- Choose the identity different from current one.

This should start your Sitecore instance.